# Function for Adding Numbers in Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXqon.png

I have tried to get results like the image, but I get these results using VBA, is there any way to use functions to get these results?

VBA code

```
Function SumNumbers(rng As Range) As Double
Dim a, e, m As Object
a = rng.Value
With CreateObject(“VBScript.RegExp”)
.Pattern = “\d+(\.\d+)?”
.Global = True
For Each e In a
If .test(e) Then
For Each m In .Execute(e)
SumNumbers = SumNumbers + Val(m.Value)
Next
End If
Next
End With
End Function
```

Please help me, so that I can get 61 results without using VBA ,thanks

Comment: So is your data always looking like that where the numbers to sum are at the front of a string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are always at the front of a string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B1:B4,SEARCH(" ",B1:B4)))
```

Comment: @Fadil Mahri You are right. This solution is very elegant. However, in any worksheet that has quantity and unit mixed into one column you are sure to have leading blanks occurring from time to time.. Perhaps JvdV can expand his idea to, at least, throw an error if an item is omitted from the total because of a leading blank, as he has pointed out that they would. Otherwise I recommend that you take other precautions to ensure that such omissions don't occur or don't go unnoticed.

Comment: @JvdV I wonder if this would address my concern: `=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B1:B4,SEARCH(" ",B1:B4,2)))` - at least for single leading blanks. Or would it be possible to incorporate a TRIM function in your formula?

Comment: It would be possible using `=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B1:B4,SEARCH(" ",TRIM(B1:B4))))` @Variatus. Still assuming numbers at the front of the string with a possible leading space. With more than one leading space: `=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(TRIM(B1:B4),SEARCH(" ",TRIM(B1:B4))))`. BTW, Find is also an alternative as per your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved your problem in my example.

1. I created a helper column. In fact, I used column C but it could be any column, preferably (but not necessarily) on the same sheet as your data.
2. I entered this formula in it's row 2 and copied down to as far as column B has data. Note that I trimmed the original text to ensure that there are no leading blanks that shouldn't be there.

   =VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(B2),FIND(" ",TRIM(B2))))
3. I hid the helper column. That wouldn't be necessary if you have it on another sheet.
4. I entered `=SUM(C2:C5)` below the last row of the original column B.
5. Done.

Comment: yes it works if i use the help column, but i want to add up right away, by the way thanks a lot for the time